# http POST/GET controller using spring framework

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc

I am trying to set up a webapp that get the body of a POST request and then create a database. I created a controller for POST and GET requests on a vFabric server using spring SVM. I started with the spring SVM web aplication template. Im using spring tool suite.

I am new to spring so I'm still grasping the concepts of bean and controllers.

my servlet configuration files goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.mongodb" />
</beans:beans>
```

Its basically a configuration I borrowed so I assume this is the problem.

the web.xml configuration goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and my main controller is this:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(HomeController.class);
    private String bodyflow;

    Coleccion Col;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getPOST(Locale locale, Model model, @RequestBody String body){
        bodyflow = "char";
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {

        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
        model.addAttribute("postRequest", bodyflow );

        return "home";
    }

}
```

The problem with this code is that whereas the GET request is receive and executed by the method "home", the method getPOST does not execute, I assume it does not get the POST request and it  I send to my server from the simple REST client google chrome. I assume is a configuration problem, do I need to add a diferent configuration to GET and POST?

You will notice that in the getPOST method I only set a variable, this is because I was testing if the problem was the model File being diferent in each method, but I realized the method isnt even running.

if you know of a better way of doing this please post it.

Thanks!

Comment: _from the simple REST client google chrome_ What is that? Your client needs to send an HTTP POST request to `domain/yourapp/`

Comment: right, I have the application running on http://localhost:8080/mongodb. Google chrome has an extension that send HTTP REST requests to a given URL, in this case on my server. When I send a GET request "home" is returned but when I send a POST request it seems nothing happens.

Comment: Is there any way to check the status code of the response your extension gets back?

Comment: yeah it prints the response of the server in plain html, its weird because I get the same response when I send GET or POST. You can check it out here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7437425/response.png

Comment: Show us what a POST looks like.

Comment: I assumme you mean the response of a POST request https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7437425/post.png, all headers and data string I put throw the same result.

Comment: The first thing you need to understand is that your Spring Controller methods both return a String, the same value actually. Spring maps this String to a jsp or html file. It renders that file to html and writes it to the response. But it seems to me like your client is sending a GET request in both cases.

Comment: They both send a mapping to home.jsp which contains the words and the atributes serverTime and postRequest created in the methods. I just tried with a diferent client and it yield the same results, however if I send for example a PUT request or any other, I dont get a response as expected.

Comment: Although, your POST handler returns the string `home`, it doesn't set the model (request) attributes for the time/date. So it shouldn't be the same as the one returned from the GET. That's why I think your client might not be doing what we think it is, ie. sending a POST.

Comment: Actually you are right, if I disable the GET method and only leave POST I wont receive response from sending POST, the server replies that GET is not supported even if I am sending POST. The funny thing is this happens with all the clients.